# Cannot find Symbol error in Java - why?

Tags: java

I am having a hard time understanding the object oriented world. I am working on a homework assignment and I can't understand why I am getting an error here. The issue I am having is in the add method. I am using the Netbeans IDE (per professor requirement) and the problem I am getting is in the `add` method. There are two errors that both say "Cannot find Symbol"; one is in reference to the variable `customers` while the other is in reference to the variable `numCustomer`. I am trying to understand what I am doing wrong, not just how to fix it.

What I have so far:

```
package homework6;

/**
 *
 * @author christian
 */

public class Homework6 {
    // Declare variables
    private int numCustomers = 0;
    private Customer customer;

    // Constructor
    public Homework6() {
        Customer[] customers = new Customer[50];
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Christian Beckman N00963294");
        System.out.println("Homework 6");
        System.out.println(); // Prints a blank line

        // Create and instance of Homework6
        Homework6 homework6 = new Homework6();
        homework6.execute(args);
    }

    private void add(Customer customer) {
        int i = 0;
        customers[i] = customer;
        i++;
        numCustomer++;
    }

    private void displayCustomers() {

    }

    private void execute(String[] args) {

    }

    private int getTotal() {

    }

    private void readFile(String filename) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Your constructor declares a new variable called `constructors`; since it's not a field it's created then immediately destroyed.  Perhaps you meant to make that as a field...?

Comment: I don't understand what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is `numCustomers` with an 's' but your method refers to `numCustomer++;`   without an 's'.

It should be:

```
numCustomers++;
```

For

```
private Customer customer;
```

it should probably be:

```
private Customer[] customers;
```

Be very careful in your code where you refer to customer and customers. It looks like you are using the convention "customer" for just one and "customers" for the array. If that is too subtle for you then consider changing to something like oneCustomer and allCustomers.

Comment: That ain't the only one.

Comment: Yes, I was adding to my post while you commented. :)

Comment: The `add` method also has an `i` which isn't needed.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, that is a very good idea. I did get this confused because of the similarities. I am not sure what you mean (4castle) when you say the add method does not need i. I realize now that the scope will not accomplish what I intended. I meant for it to increment the array index, but I will need to make it global in order to accomplish this. Is that what you were referring to?

Answer (score 0):

You create an array of `Customer` objects in the constructor, then the array is immediately destroyed. Try declaring it like this:

```
public class Homework6 {
    // Declare variables
    private int numCustomers = 0;
    private int i = 0;
    private Customer customer;
    private Customer[] customers;

    // Constructor
    public Homework6() {
        customers = new Customer[50];
    }
...
```

The reason for this, is any variables declared inside a method (in this case, the constructor) has something called local scope which means it can ONLY be accessed inside that method. The variables you declare outside the methods have something called global scope, which means that variable can be accessed across all the methods in a class.

For the same reason as above, `i` will keep resetting to 0 each time you call the add function. To fix that, declare `private int i = 0` above the constructor with the other variables. Then write the method like so:

```
private void add(Customer customer) {
        customers[i] = customer;
        i++;
        numCustomers++;
    }
```

Also, whenever you do `numCustomer++` in the add method, you should put `numCustomers++` like above because you declared `numCustomers` with an 's' at the end. Has to match EXACTLY.

Comment: OK so I am just getting back to this problem. I am a bit confused why you say the array in my constructor is created and then instantly destroyed. My professor said the way you explicitly create an array of a specific size is ....... ArrayType[] nameOfArray = new ArrayType[arraySize];

Comment: I see the issue with the scope of my variable "i" and with the variable name not being numCostomers++. Thank you for your help, and if you could explain what it is I am doing wrong with the array issue that I mentioned above I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @user43378 You can declare variables as global or local variables. Global variables can be used throughout the entire class whereas local variables can only be used in a singular method. Since you put `Customer[] customers` within the constructor, you made the array a local variable. This array can only be used in the constructor as it has a local scope. If you declare the array outside of a method like in my example above, this has a global scope. Since you declared it outside of any method, it can be used throughout the class.

Comment: Thank you that makes perfect sense but I never though of it cause it was an array